# Rails Controller Models Naming Convention Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I am a newbie to Ruby on Rails and trying to setup oracle based ROR application,

The DB table name is `booker.live_edi_vendors`

I have my controller defined in the following path:

```
../rails-root/app/controller/live_edi_vendors_controller.rb
```

And the content is:

```
 class LiveEdiVendorsController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @name = request.env['REMOTE_USER']
    end
 end
```

I also created a view for this controller, which is in `../rails-root/app/views/live_edi_vendors` folder.

And I have put some code in `index.html.erb` inside this directory.

Now, my model file is `../rails-root/app/model/live_edi_vendors.rb`

and the content in this file is:

```
class LiveEdiVendors < ActiveRecord::Base
      set_primary_key "live_edi_vendor_id"
      set_table_name "booker.live_edi_vendors"

      def LiveEdiVendors.find_by_legal_entity_id(legal_entity_id)
          return "asdadsad" #testing (temporary)
      end
  end
```

Now,

When i am trying to access the path `<website host>/live_edi_vendors` from browser, it says

```
uninitialized constant LiveEdiVendorsController
```

My `routes.rb` file is having the following line to route the request:

```
map.vendorlivelist 'live_edi_vendors/:action', :controller => 'live_edi_vendors'
```

Please, help me out, I struggling with these naming conventions a lot these days.

I am also putting my directory structure here:

```
app
|-- controllers
|   `-- live_edi_vendors_controller.rb
|-- model
|   `-- live_edi_vendors.rb
`-- views
    |-- layouts
    `-- live_edi_vendors
        `-- index.html.erb
```

Thanks,

Comment: Singular for the Model and Plural for the Controller.

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code. Have you tried restarting the server?

Comment: Thanks mischa, restarting the server did the trick :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hmm Model name are always singular
try

```
class LiveEdiVendor < ActiveRecord::Base
  ....
end
```

and model file name too

```
live_edi_vendor.rb
```

Comment: done so, but didnt happen anything. 

Actually it's problem with controller itself i think as even if i am not using model, it says "uninitialized constant LiveEdiVendorsController"

Comment: my controller file name is live_edi_vendors_controller.rb and  class name is "LiveEdiVendorsController"